# Android: Sharing webview across activites

Tags: android

Is it possible to share a same webview object in two different activities in android ? Here is my use case. I have an Activity A that has a webview W. W occupies 50% of A. Now When I click on Webview W, in activity A, I want to launch Activity B with whole of it occupying webview W. In acitivity B, I do not want webview to requery the URI. Is it possible to do this in android ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe so, think Android is one activity at a time. But the crux of your question is preserving the work already done in webview w.  Why not let one activity control both browsers and copy the data from one webview to the other.  Copying history might be tricky but the rest should be easy.

Comment: Sharing webview might be useful if the web content contains an image that is fetched from a url in HTML page. we obviously don't want to reload the same image again and again.